# Scheduling policy and priority using pthread does not make any difference

Tags: linux, multithreading, linux-kernel, pthreads

I am running a simple multi-threaded program using pthread. Considering using real-scheduler (SCHED_FIFO policy), lower priority threads won't be able to run until higher priority ones are finished. But, when I run two versions of this program (the only difference is priority 99->1) at the same time, they finish at almost the same time. I even changed the policy to SCHED_OTHER but still no difference.

```
# include <stdio.h>
# include <string.h>
# include <pthread.h>
# include <stdlib.h>
# include <unistd.h>
# include <math.h>

# define NUM_THREADS    128

pthread_t tid[NUM_THREADS];
int indexes[NUM_THREADS];

void* dummyThread(void *arg)
{
    unsigned long i = 0;
    pthread_t id = pthread_self();
    float a, b = 5, c = 8;

    printf("Thread %d started.\n", *(int*)arg + 1);

    for(i = 0; i < 10000000; i++)
        a = sin(b) + sqrt(b);
    
    printf("Thread %d finished.\n", *(int*)arg + 1);

    return NULL;
}

int main(void)
{
    int i = 0;
    pthread_attr_t attr;
    struct sched_param schedParam;
    struct timespec start, finish;
    double elapsed;

    pthread_attr_init(&attr);
    pthread_attr_setschedpolicy(&attr, SCHED_FIFO);
    schedParam.sched_priority = 1;
    pthread_attr_setschedparam(&attr, &schedParam);
    pthread_attr_setinheritsched(&attr, PTHREAD_EXPLICIT_SCHED);

    clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &start);

    for (i = 0 ; i < NUM_THREADS; i++)
    {
        indexes[i] = i;

        if (!pthread_create((void*)&tid[i], &attr, &dummyThread, &indexes[i]))
            printf("Thread %d created successfully.\n", i + 1);
        
        else
            printf("Failed to create Thread %d.\n", i + 1);
    }

    for (i = 0 ; i < NUM_THREADS; i++)
        pthread_join(tid[i], NULL);

    clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &finish);
    elapsed = (finish.tv_sec - start.tv_sec);
    elapsed += (finish.tv_nsec - start.tv_nsec) / 1000000000.0;
    printf("%lf\n", elapsed);

    return 0;
}
```

Edit 1: Updated my code by adding `pthread_attr_setschedparam` and error checking. I don't get any errors when running it without sudo, and changing priority or scheduling policy still does not change the result.

Edit 2: I noticed that when I create threads with different priorities within the same process it works well. In the following code for threads with even index I assign priority 1 while for threads with an odd index I assign priority 99. It works well and odd threads finish first before even threads.

```
# include <stdio.h>
# include <string.h>
# include <pthread.h>
# include <stdlib.h>
# include <unistd.h>
# include <math.h>

# define NUM_THREADS    128

pthread_t tid[NUM_THREADS];
int indexes[NUM_THREADS];

void* dummyThread(void *arg)
{
    unsigned long i = 0;
    pthread_t id = pthread_self();
    float a, b = 5, c = 8;

    printf("Thread %d started.\n", *(int*)arg);

    for(i = 0; i < 10000000; i++)
        a = sin(b) + sqrt(b);
    
    printf("Thread %d finished.\n", *(int*)arg);

    return NULL;
}

int main(void)
{
    int i = 0;
    pthread_attr_t attr;
    struct sched_param schedParam;
    struct timespec start, finish;
    double elapsed;

    clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &start);

    for (i = 0 ; i < NUM_THREADS; i++)
    {
        indexes[i] = i;

        pthread_attr_init(&attr);
        pthread_attr_setschedpolicy(&attr, SCHED_FIFO);
        schedParam.sched_priority = i % 2 == 0 ? 1 : 99;
        pthread_attr_setschedparam(&attr, &schedParam);
        pthread_attr_setinheritsched(&attr, PTHREAD_EXPLICIT_SCHED);

        if (!pthread_create((void*)&tid[i], &attr, &dummyThread, &indexes[i]))
            printf("Thread %d created successfully.\n", i);
        
        else
            printf("Failed to create Thread %d.\n", i);
    }

    for (i = 0 ; i < NUM_THREADS; i++)
        pthread_join(tid[i], NULL);

    clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &finish);
    elapsed = (finish.tv_sec - start.tv_sec);
    elapsed += (finish.tv_nsec - start.tv_nsec) / 1000000000.0;
    printf("%lf\n", elapsed);

    return 0;
}
```

Since threads from different processes are all sent to the same scheduler in the Kernel, I don't know why it does not work with different processes.

Comment: Why would there be any difference?   There is X amount of work to be done with N cores.  Altering the priorities does not change that.

Comment: The _first_ thing you need to do is check all `pthread_..` functions for error return. Unless you are running the binary as `root`, your `pthread_attr_setschedparam` is likely failing.

Comment: @MartinJames Yes, the amount of work is the same. But when all the CPU cores are occupied, the scheduler prioritizes threads with higher priority. What is the priority for, if they are going to share the same amount of CPU time when running in parallel eitherway?

Comment: @EmployedRussian Yes, I have checked that. There are no errors and they run properly. I have simplified the code above, but I check for errors when creating threads and also have printf statements inside threads to make sure they run properly.

Answer (score 0):

From man [pthread_attr_setschedpolicy](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_attr_setschedpolicy.3.html)

> In order for the policy setting made by
> pthread_attr_setschedpolicy() to have effect when calling
> pthread_create(3), the caller must use
> pthread_attr_setinheritsched(3) to set the inherit-scheduler
> attribute of the attributes object attr to
> PTHREAD_EXPLICIT_SCHED.

You've neglected to do that, so your `SCHED_FIFO` didn't have any effect.

As soon as I add `pthread_attr_setinheritsched(&attr, PTHREAD_EXPLICIT_SCHED);` call, `pthread_create()` starts failing with `EPERM` (since only `root` can create `SCHED_FIFO` threads).

Comment: It's interesting, cause even when I add `pthread_attr_setinheritsched(&attr, PTHREAD_EXPLICIT_SCHED)`, I don't get any errors. And with or without using `sudo` to run the code, it still neglects the priority and scheduler.

Comment: Do you have any idea why this happens?

Comment: @AmirFakhimBabaei I do not. Maybe you added `pthread_attr_setinheritsched()` in the wrong place? I added it immediately after the `pthread_attr_setschedparam()` call. Did you check that it succeeds? Edit your question and show _exact_ source, with error checking included?

Comment: I just updated my code.

Comment: @AmirFakhimBabaei Running your exact code gives me `Failed to create Thread 1. Failed to create Thread 2. ...`. What Linux and `libc` are you using? Are you running this under `WSL2` or some kind of emulator? I don't see how this code could be working without `sudo`.

Comment: I'm using Fedora with 5.13v Kernel in VirtualBox. Actually, I noticed that it works well when creating threads with different priorities in the same process. But, when I run them in two distinct processes at the same time it's like the priority and scheduling policy does not matter. I will update my post.